# Can Codename One BrowserComponent show WebGL?

Tags: webgl, codenameone

A premise, in case it makes any difference: I've deleted the CEF folder, since with it the BrowserComponent didn't work for me, and installed the ZuluFX Java 1.8 (with later versions, like ZuluFX 1.11, BrowserComponent didn't work either; this, on a side note, might be related to the same issue that has Cordova when one tries to work with Java > 8).

The problem: using BrowserComponent.setPage with a string, I can create, indeed, programmatically and on the fly, a html page which is properly shown.

When I use an example from BabylonJS (a string containng a html file which loads a cube, loaded as asset, and shows it: the html page  -of course- works when loaded in a normal browser) nothing happens, at least in the simulator.

Before to start to make hypothesis (maybe the problem is in loading the cube; maybe in loading the scripts; maybe it can't work in simulators, but will work in the app; etc.) I'd like to know if BrowserComponent is supposed to work with WebGL.

Comment: WebGL should work when on Android, and iOS.  In simulator and desktop it will only work when using CEF.

Comment: Ah, so the problem is that I removed CEF. Good that I mentioned it in the premise. Thanks. :)

Comment: What was the problem with CEF? Did you try getting CEF working with the Maven build? It should work better.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Eh, problem was it didn't show the html at all, not even a linked page. It returned an error on the line of "Failed to create CEF browser". After some research, the easier solution to me seemed to be moving to JavaFX. Now I probably will install Maven, build Codename One from source (I think this is required, right?) and try the Maven Template, to see if the page appears in the simulator. Thanks again for your time. :)

Comment: No. Maven works as usual by default, you don't need to build from source. See the video here: https://www.codenameone.com/getting-started.html